# In EpiServer 8, how can I extend the Scheduled Publish event?

Tags: c#, episerver

I'm working with EpiServer 8, and need to execute a custom API call when a scheduled publish is saved.  Currently I'm able to capture immediate publish events via an Initialization Module, like so:

```
[InitializableModule]
[ModuleDependency(typeof(EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule))]
public class ContentEventInitializer : IInitializableModule
{
    public void Initialize(InitializationEngine initializationEngine)
    {
        var events = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentEvents>();
        events.PublishingContent += EventsPublishingContent;
    }

    public void Preload(string[] parameters)
    {
    }

    public void Uninitialize(InitializationEngine initializationEngine)
    {
        var events = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentEvents>();
        events.PublishingContent -= EventsPublishingContent;
    }

    private void EventsPublishingContent(object sender, ContentEventArgs contentEventArgs)
    {
        // Tell our API that maintenance started.
    }
}
```

The above EventsPublishingContent event works when an editor publishes the content immediately.  The Visual Studio break-point on that method gets hit successfully.  But it doesn't get executed when a site editor chooses to "Schedule for Publish."

When an editor is viewing the "Schedule for Publish" dialog, and selects the "Schedule" button, I would like to capture the following and send it to our API:

- The "Publish changes on" value.
- The pages that will be published.

What is the proper approach to doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: How long was time window between scheduling the publish? Are you sure that there wasn't app pool recycles between editor action and actual scheduled job execution? Looking at code of the job - it called Publish() action on content repository that should fire up publishing / published events.

Comment: Thanks Valdis. Presently this project is still in development, and I'm the editor doing the programming and testing.  Essentially I want to intercept that "Schedule for Publish" event so I can send the publish timestamp and pages that will get published to a separate API.

Comment: Sounds like you could potentially wire up the *ContentSaved* event and look at the *StartPublish* property of the content?

Comment: Ah, that may be the trick @TedNyberg. After adding events.SavedContent to the initialize method, I'm able to hit a breakpoint when the "Schedule" button is selected.  Now just to figure out where/if ContentEventArgs contain the timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are key pieces from the solution that I ran with.  Ultimately I stuck break-points in about a dozen potential events from IContentEvents, and isolated 2 that were useful for my purposes.  Unfortunately I had to fetch the scheduled-publish timestamp from the EpiServer database.  A few TODO notes in the code are provided, and this is just to streamline the answer.

Remarks in the code are based on my observations.  I'm not an EpiServer guru.

```
using EPiServer;
using EPiServer.Core;
using EPiServer.Framework;
using EPiServer.Framework.Initialization;
using EPiServer.ServiceLocation;

namespace MySite.Helpers
{
    [InitializableModule]
    [ModuleDependency(typeof(EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule))]
    public class ContentEventInitializer : IInitializableModule
    {
        public void Initialize(InitializationEngine initializationEngine)
        {
            var events = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentEvents>();
            events.CheckedInContent += checkedInContent;
            events.PublishedContent += publishedContent;   
        }

        public void Uninitialize(InitializationEngine initializationEngine)
        {
            var events = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentEvents>();
            events.CheckedInContent -= checkedInContent;
            events.PublishedContent -= publishedContent;   
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when a version of a content item has been checked in.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This is called after a scheduled publish gets saved.  It's not called after an immediate publish.
        /// Useful for executing custom events following a scheduled publish.  When this event occurs,
        /// you can fetch the publish timestamp from dbo.tblWorkContent.DelayPublishUntil.
        /// Prior to this event the DelayPublishUntil value will be NULL.
        /// </remarks>
        public static void checkedInContent(object sender, ContentEventArgs contentEventArgs)
        {
            // Fetch timestamp from dbo.tblWorkContent.DelayPublishUntil.
            ConnectInfo connectInfo = new ConnectInfo("MyEpiServerDatabase");
            PlannedMaintenanceInfo plannedMaintenanceInfo = new PlannedMaintenanceInfo(ref connectInfo, contentEventArgs.Content.ContentLink.WorkID);
            connectInfo = null;
            // The PlannedMaintenanceInfo method above uses the following SQL query:
            //    string query = string.Format("SELECT URLSegment, DelayPublishUntil FROM tblWorkContent WHERE pkId = {0}", WorkID);

            // TODO: Notify API about this planned maintenance window.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when a content item or a version of a content item has been published.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This is called after an immediate publish.  It's not called after a scheduled publish gets saved.
        /// Useful for executing custom events following an immediate publish.
        /// </remarks>
        public void publishedContent(object sender, ContentEventArgs contentEventArgs)
        {
            // TODO: Notify API that an immediate maintenance window has started.
        }
    }
}
```

The data retrieval code and other moving parts are omitted for brevity. If you're reading this, I assume you know how to get the data, and have your own preferences or framework for doing that anyways.  The actual SQL query that I wrote is in the comments of the checkedInContent method.  So you can take that and run with it in your own database.  What's important there, is making sure you pass the WorkID to the query.  That ID comes from contentEventArgs.Content.ContentLink.WorkID.

I wish that EpiServer exposed that timestamp value which eventually gets saved to tblWorkContent.DelayPublishUntil during the form submission.  That way it wouldn't be necessary to fetch the value from the database.  That in turn would make it easier to reuse this in a more generic way, where we wouldn't need to provide the database connection string to extract that timestamp.  If that value is exposed in some property, and I'm just missing it, please let me know.

I hope this code helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

When using "Schedule for publish", the page will be published by a scheduled job, I don't think that any events will be triggered by that, at least it doesn't seems like it, more info here: http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Petra-Liljecrantz/Dates/2016/3/differences-between-scheduled-publish-and-normal-publish/

Comment: Thanks for that link. Maybe I need to create a task to look at the DelayPublishUntil field in tblWorkContent. When a scheduled publish is saved, that appears to be where the value goes. It would be nice if I could capture that click event on the "Schedule" button.